# Is there a way to allow at most one selection per category in a hierarchical slicer in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, slicers

I'm using PowerBI to represent the costs of various different technologies. Some of these technologies have various different costs according to different assumptions (and others do not).

I would like a to use a hierarchical slicer to allow the user to see the cost at most one option from each technology category at the same time (to compare the technologies under different assumptions - entries may be along the lines of "technology A - high", "Technology B - low", "central case"). I would like to be able to compare "technology A - high" with "technology B - low" however, so a normal slicer with simplified names wouldn't work. Most of the standard options allow either no restrictions or only the ability to limit users to selecting one option across the whole data set.

Is my proposed idea possible in Power BI?